# IDERA suggests to alter procedures in tempdb

Tags: sql-server, tempdb

Idera analysis is suggesting I:

```
USE [tempdb]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON


GO
ALTER PROC ##zDP_235302...
```

Is this really a good idea? Most of the "fixes" their diagnostic software suggests is spot on, but this kind of makes me take a step back. There is a long list of these procedures in tempdb they suggest altering.

Comment: I don't get their suggestion. Is it telling you to change the SET options? Or suggesting you use temporary stored procedure? Could you elaborate what it shows?

Comment: Is this Dynamics?

Comment: SQL Module tempdb.dbo.##zDP_2353027SD was found with ANSI_NULLS and/or QUOTED_IDENTIFIER set to OFF.  These settings can prevent the query optimizer from using an index seek for certain queries.

Comment: it is dynamics GP

Comment: Here is another smaller query example:      USE [tempdb]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO

ALTER PROC ##zDP_1450622S_1 (@RunReportID int) AS /* 14.00.0085.000 */ set nocount on SELECT TOP 1  RunReportID, Group_ID, CMPANYID, USERID, MasterDocumentName, OutputFileType, DATE1, TIME1, Count1, SuccessCount, FailureCount, Status, PRTOSCRN, PRTOPRTR, PRNTOFIL, ERRSTATE, DEX_ROW_ID FROM .##1450622 WHERE RunReportID = @RunReportID ORDER BY RunReportID ASC set nocount off

Comment: I guess my real question is it safe to alter stored procs in tempdb. My gut feeling says no, but I wanted to hear it from the pro's.

Answer (score 0):

There's no harm in doing it, but it'll just go away next time the service is restarted. If it's something that really needs to be done, you'd have to alter the code that is creating the procedure, wherever that lives. It could be they are in the [model](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/05/creating-tables-stored-procedures-tempdb-permanently/) database.

Comment: How do you know there's no harm if you haven't seen the change?

Comment: good point but I do have a little trust in Idera...if it has DROP DATABASE in it I would think they'd get a few calls.

Comment: Best of luck with that.